# Finding points that sit near the X and Y axes in a scatter plot

Tags: java, r, plot, statistics

I have a particular problem involving a scatter plot I am trying to create. I have a file that contains data in the following format: Each Name is unique and the CompanyScore and CommunityScore are integer values.

```
Name    CompanyScore   CommunityScore
Patrick 8383           99000
```

The file goes on in the same format for quite some time. I am trying to figure out the top twenty points on a scatterplot that would be near the X (CompanyScore) and Y (CommunityScore) axes. There is probably some mathematical way to do this but at the moment I am at a complete loss. Ideally I would probably have to make the scatter plot in Java from the file and then it shouldn't be too hard to figure out the closest values to the X and Y axes right? I'm not sure if there's a library for this type of thing or not. I know there are statistics tools like R but I think it may be almost easier to just see the details in Java. Hopefully this is not a long shot. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The points closest to the X and Y axes are those whose values (CompanyScore and CommunityScore) are closest to zero.

Comment: Maybe you mean closest to the origin? That would be `data[order(sqrt(data$Company^2+data$CommunityScore^2))[1:20],]`.

Comment: The person with the largest combined score is the one with the largest: `Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);`  (the distance from the origin to the point).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the points who are closest to X *or* closest to Y, then just pick the ones with the lowest X or Y scores.

If you're looking for the points who are closest to X *and* closest to Y, then calculate the distance from that point to zero:

```
distances = sqrt(i * ((x - min_x) / (max_x - min_x))^2 + 
                 j * ((y - min_y) / (max_y - min_y))^2 )

where i + j = 1.0, and 0.0 <= i, j <= 1.0 with i and j being the weight
constants if you want to emphasize one axis over the other
```

and then take the smallest of those distances.

Comment: I don't know if the OP wanted the combined distance, instead of 2 lists (in my interpretation), but if so, note that this solution will be dominated by the variable with the larger scale, unless they are on the same scale. I don't think it is safe to assume that they are, & the example also seems to suggest otherwise. If your interpretation of the question is correct, you may want to *normalize* both variables before calculating the Euclidean distance.

Comment: @gung That is a good point, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, @sdasdadas. Unfortunately, that formula for normalization will only work in simple cases. A more robust formula for normalizing would be `(x - min_x)/(max_x - min_x)`. On the other hand, (arguing w/ myself now) if the OP wants combined distance, they may want it to be dominated by one variable; this point needs to be clarified...

Comment: @gung Edited again. :D

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the 20 rows with the lowest `CompanyScore` values, and the 20 rows with the lowest `CommunityScore` values.  You can do this with [?order](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html) and [?head](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/head.html).  Try:

```
head(myData[order(myData$CompanyScore)],   n=20)
head(myData[order(myData$CommunityScore)], n=20)
```

I'm assuming that all values are positive.  If you want the values that are closest to 0, and some are negative, you could use `abs(myData$CompanyScore)`, e.g., inside the `order()` call instead.